# Можно ли назвать популярный маршрут расхожим?

Tags: точное-словоупотребление

> **Монастырь расположен вдали от расхожих туристических маршрутов**, а гостиничный комплекс для желающих принимать здесь лечебные ванны был
>   пока **ещё** не достроен, оттого чужие, да **ещё** и к вечеру, были
>   настоящим чудом.

Как уйти от второго "ещё"?

Comment: Как уйти от второго "ещё"? --- заменить на "особенно". Оно больше подходит.

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем удачное употребление слова: обычно оно относится к чему-нибудь *раздаваемому* или *продаваемому*, которое хорошо **расходится**. Даже если говорить о торговле путевками по маршрутам, стандартный смысл путается с буквальным "*хождением* по маршрутам". В зависимости от желания придать нейтральную или негативную (в той или иной степени) оценку туристическим маршрутам, можно говорить об *исхоженных* тропах, *избитых* либо *излюбленных туристами* маршрутах и т. п. Вместо "*да ещё и*" можно "**и вдобавок**" приделать.

Comment: Интересно! Знал "избитый" только в смысле "заезженный", "надоевший", а теперь на Грамоте нашёл другой смысл — как раз тот, в котором вы его употребили (под цифрой 1).

Answer (score 1):

Монастырь расположен вдали от ***расхожих*** туристических маршрутов, а гостиничный комплекс для желающих принимать  лечебные ванны **пока  не достроен**, оттого чужие, **да ещё и к вечеру,** были настоящим чудом.

1) Надо пожертвовать одним ***еще***: пока еще не достроен — здесь *еще* имеет усилительное значение, а не основное.

2) ***К тому же к вечеру*** — повторяется предлог и падеж, а это  стилистический недочет, также можно понять как "к тому же вечеру".

3) Слово ***расхожие*** надо оставить, у него есть такие синонимы, как ***популярный, общеизвестный***, причем без негативной коннотации (расхожая легенда, мудрость, цитата, термин, идея).  Так как **сочетание авторского характера**, то можно записать **курсивом** (это красиво, лучше кавычек).

**Заменять синонимом нежелательно**, в данном сочетании это авторский стиль, а вот слова *популярный, общеизвестный* как раз **банальны, нейтральны, без интересной окраски.**